Writing $\int_\Omega (\nabla \cdot \phi)|\nabla u|^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^n \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi^i \partial_i u $ as divergence of a vector field
Let $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega; \mathbb{R}^n)$ and $u\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth. Denote the components of $\phi$ by $\phi=(\phi^1, ..., \phi^n)$. Denote $\partial_i = \partial_{x_i}$ to be the partial differentiation.
Is it possible to write
$$\int_\Omega (\nabla \cdot \phi)|\nabla u|^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^n \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi^i  \partial_i u $$
in terms of a divergence of some vector function? I.e. is the above equal to $$\int_\Omega \nabla \cdot B$$ for some vector field $B$?
I was told that in fact the above is
$$\int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \left(|\nabla u|^2\phi - 2\phi \cdot \nabla u \nabla u\right)$$
but I couldn't prove this is true. Can someone help?

The derivative of something is the sum of the derivatives of its pieces. This is a very general principle.
Using this principle
$$
  \nabla\cdot(\phi|\nabla u|^2) = (\nabla\cdot\phi)|\nabla u|^2 + \phi\cdot(\nabla|\nabla u|^2).
$$
The second term is a directional derivative and follows the product rule (which is really just a manifestation of the same principle we just used):
$$
  \phi\cdot\nabla|\nabla u|^2 = (\phi\cdot\nabla[\nabla u])\cdot\nabla u + \nabla u\cdot(\phi\cdot\nabla[\nabla u]) = 2\nabla u\cdot(\phi\cdot\nabla[\nabla u]).
$$
Thus all together
$$
  \nabla\cdot(\phi|\nabla u|^2) = \nabla\cdot\phi|\nabla u|^2 + 2\nabla u\cdot(\phi\cdot\nabla[\nabla u]) 
$$
and rearranging gives
$$
  \nabla\cdot\phi|\nabla u|^2 = \nabla\cdot(\phi|\nabla u|^2) - 2\nabla u\cdot(\phi\cdot\nabla[\nabla u]).
$$
However
$$
  2\nabla u\cdot(\phi\cdot\nabla[\nabla u]) = 2\sum_i\nabla u\cdot(\phi^i\partial_i\nabla u) \ne 2\sum_i\nabla u\cdot(\nabla\phi^i\partial_iu)
$$
so I suspect your expression is not a divergence, or perhaps your expression was incorrect to begin with.
